# Disable textboxes based on radio button selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three radio buttons and five text boxes in my web page. I want to disable text boxes based on the radio box selection. This code is working fine but when I check a different radio button the previous gray textbox is not turning white. Please correct me I have tried several ways it did not work.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtName.Enabled = false;
            txtTitle.Enabled = false;
            txtOrganization.Enabled = false;
            txtPhone.Enabled = false;
            txtEmail.Enabled = false;

        }
        if (rdPhone.Checked == true)
        {
            txtName.Enabled = true;
            txtName.Focus();
            txtTitle.Enabled = true;
            txtOrganization.Enabled = true;
            txtPhone.Enabled = true;
            txtEmail.Enabled = false;
            txtEmail.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        }
        if (rdEmail.Checked == true)
        {
            txtName.Enabled = true;
            txtName.Focus();
            txtTitle.Enabled = true;
            txtOrganization.Enabled = true;
            txtPhone.Enabled = false;
            txtPhone.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            txtEmail.Enabled = true;
        }

        if (rdDoNotContact.Checked == true)
        {
            txtName.Enabled = false;
            txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            txtTitle.Enabled = false;
            txtTitle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            txtOrganization.Enabled = false;
            txtOrganization.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            txtPhone.Enabled = false;
            txtPhone.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            txtEmail.Enabled = false;
            txtEmail.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the color to lightgray if you disable the TextBox but you are not changing it back when you enable it:

```
txtEmail.Enabled = true;
txtEmail.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I also have validations based on the users selection he is supposed to enter the data in the respected text boxes since I am using a disable function I am not able to figure out a way for it. I am using requiredfieldvalidator.

Comment: Im not sure if i understand the problem, however, you can also enable/disable validators.